# For loops in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, for-loop

I am using angularjs. I have two for loops, one incrementing as 0, 2 and other as 1, 3... Is there a more elegant way to do this? Such as, a variable which alternates its value for every loop iteration so that the two loops can be combined? Thanks.

```js
for ( jCounter= 0; jCounter< truthArray.length; jCounter+=2 ) {
    for ( iCounter= 0 ; iCounter< truthArray.length; iCounter++ ) {
        if (index.indexOf(iCounter) === jCounter&& index.indexOf(iCounter) !== -1) {
            last[iCounter] = 'left';
        }
    }
}
            
for ( jCounter= 1; jCounter< truthArray.length; jCounter+=2 ) {
    for ( iCounter= 0 ; iCounter< truthArray.length; iCounter++ ) {
        if (index.indexOf(iCounter) === jCounter&& index.indexOf(iCounter) !== -1) {
            last[iCounter] = 'right';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `map[i] = i % 2 === 0 ? 'left' : 'right';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the work

```js
for ( jCounter= 0; jCounter< truthArray.length; jCounter++ ) {
  for ( iCounter= 0 ; iCounter< truthArray.length; iCounter++ ) {
    if (index.indexOf(iCounter) > -1 && index.indexOf(iCounter) === jCounter) {
      last[iCounter] = jCounter%2 == 0 ? 'left' : 'right';                            
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) `%` to know if it's an odd or even number.

```
for (let jCounter = 0; jCounter< truthArray.length; jCounter++ ) {
    for (let iCounter = 0 ; iCounter< truthArray.length; iCounter++ ) {
        if (index.indexOf(iCounter) === jCounter && index.indexOf(iCounter) !== -1) {
            last[iCounter] = jCounter % 2 === 0 ? 'left' : 'right';
        }
    }
}
```

Also, you should declare a variable before using it (`jCounter` and `iCounter`). [In strict mode is forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6133741/1918287).

Answer (score 0):

Try do this format...

for ( jCounter= 0; jCounter< truthArray.length; jCounter++ ) {

```
   for ( iCounter= 0 ; iCounter< truthArray.length; iCounter++ ) {

                   //write something here.
```

}
}